# How do I add an css background image in a Vue file?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to replace the navigation drawer with an image I have `(./src/assets/image.jpg)`

```html
  <v-navigation-drawer
    mini-variant
    dark
    app
    permanent
    class="withBackground"
  >
...
<style scoped>
.withBackground {
  background: rgba(-1, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: // what here?;
}
</style>
```

I have no idea what to set to `background-image`. Should I load the image via `import` and attach it to a `data` field and then place it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `src` attribute.

You could do:

```
  <v-navigation-drawer
    mini-variant
    dark
    app
    permanent
    src="./src/assets/image.jpg"
  >
```

Or if the image source is a variable something like this:

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    mini-variant
    dark
    app
    permanent
    :src="imageSrc"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
          imageSrc: null
        };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.imageSrc = require('./src/assets/image.jpg')
    },
};
</script>
```

For more info:
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/#navigation-drawer